# Swiper is not sliding in some situations

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic7

The scrolling operation is successfully from the area I marked in red. But scrolling is not possible outside the red area. I wonder what is the reason? I am using Ionic 7

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN6ge.png)

```
<swiper-container style="height: auto !important;" #swiper (slidechange)="swiperSlideChanged($event)" (afterinit)="swiperReady()">
    <swiper-slide style="height: auto !important;">
        ...
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide style="height: auto !important;">
        ...
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

swiper-container {
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: var(--ion-color-step-200, #cccccc);
  --swiper-pagination-color: var(--ion-color-primary, #3880ff);
  --swiper-pagination-progressbar-bg-color: rgba(var(--ion-text-color-rgb, 0, 0, 0), 0.25);
  --swiper-scrollbar-bg-color: rgba(var(--ion-text-color-rgb, 0, 0, 0), 0.1);
  --swiper-scrollbar-drag-bg-color: rgba(var(--ion-text-color-rgb, 0, 0, 0), 0.5);
}

swiper-slide {
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: you need to make your swiper full screen to swipe it.

Comment: when I set the height to 100%, scrolling is disabled. And since scroll is not working, some information is not visible.